# SUM ADD Different Table same ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I have no idea of how to resolve this..

```
SELECT c.NIF,
  v.preu
FROM CLIENTS c
INNER JOIN RESERVES_VIATGES r
INNER JOIN VIATGES v
ON r.CODI_VIATGE = v.CODI
ON c.NIF         = r.NIF_CLIENT
GROUP BY c.NIF, v.preu;
```

This query returns 2 column like:

```
NIF  PRICE
111   200
222   600
111   100
```

I want to select the SUM of price that have the same NIF. 
How Can I do it? Thanks

Comment: Did you really write the first query?  This is a simple modification, by including `sum(v.preu)` and removing `preu` from the `group by`.  Also, you should place the `on` clauses after each `inner join`.   Otherwise, the `from` clause is quite hard to make sense of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SUM()` aggregate function and remove `v.preu` from your `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT c.NIF,
  SUM(v.preu) preu
FROM CLIENTS c
INNER JOIN RESERVES_VIATGES r
ON c.NIF         = r.NIF_CLIENT
INNER JOIN VIATGES v
ON r.CODI_VIATGE = v.CODI
GROUP BY c.NIF;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `SUM()` aggregate function like

```
SELECT c.NIF, sum(v.preu) as Sum_price
FROM CLIENTS c
INNER JOIN RESERVES_VIATGES r
ON c.NIF = r.NIF_CLIENT
INNER JOIN VIATGES v
ON r.CODI_VIATGE = v.CODI
GROUP BY c.NIF;
```

Comment: He needs to exclude `v.preu` from the `GROUP BY` as well